# Singleton and factory pattern implementation in an exercise

Tags: java

I have to write a program described below, but I don't exactly understand how this task should be accomplished. So, this is what I have to do:

1. I have to create class **School** using singleton pattern and add attribute name and main() method to the class.
2. Then create an array of objects with 10 Student objects and 1 Teacher object using factory pattern, and invoke work() method of all these objects.
3. Next, create class **PersonFactory** with method createPerson(...), which creates either Student or Teacher depending on passed parameter.
4. Create class **Student** with property name and default value "Student" with method work(), which prints on console *name is learning* where name is value of the name property.
   5.Create class **Teacher** with property name and default value "Teacher" with method work(), which prints on console *name is teaching*.
5. Finally, create get..() and set..() methods to get/set attribute values, where necessary.

Having very little experience in Java and programming as such, this is proving to be somewhat challenging for me. This is what I have so far:

**School** class.

```
public class School {

// from what I understood, lazy instantiation 
//can be used, or am I wrong?

private String name;

private static School instance = null;

protected School() {
}

public static School getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new School();
    }
    return instance;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Usual way
    String[] Student = new String[11];
    for (int i = 1; i < Student.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Student no: " + i);

        Teacher theTeacher = new Teacher();

        //Student.work();
        //Teacher.work();

    }
}}
```

**Teacher** class.

```
public class Teacher  {
private String name = this.name = "Teacher"; //most likely wrong

public void work() {
        System.out.println(" is teaching...");
    }
}
```

**PersonFactory** class.

```
   public class PersonFactory {

    public void createPerson() {

    }
}
```

**Student** class.

```
public class Student  {
    private String name = this.name = "Student";

    public void work() {
        System.out.println("is learning...");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand in your assignment?

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: I dont understand how exactly I should do this, because I have very little experience.

Comment: and this means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to do your assignment for you, but here are some comments about your code that can lead you in the right direction :

1. You got the singleton right.
2. `PersonFactory` implies that this class should produce instances of `Person`. So `createPerson` should return a `Person`. Now, since `createPerson` should create either a `Student` or a `Teacher`, this implies that both `Student` and `Teacher` should have a common base class - `Person`. The `createPerson` should have a parameter that determines whether a `Teacher` or `Student` is created. The simplest way to do it (though not the best in terms of object oriented programming) is have a boolean parameter, such as `isTeacher`.
3. Your main method has some problems - you want to create an array of 11 `Person` objects (not `String`), that can contain the `Teacher` and the `Student`s - `Person persons = new Person[11]`. Your loop should start from `i=0`. Inside the loop you should call the `PersonFactory.createPerson(isTeacher)` to create the instances of `Teacher` and `Student`s, and assign them to the array.
4. `private String name = this.name = "Teacher";` should be `private String name = "Teacher";`. However, you want to move the methods and members that Teacher and Student have in common (such as `name` and `work`) to the base class Person.

Comment: I am not asking somebody to do it for me, I just want to be pushed in the right direction. Thanks for answer :).